# How do I make a circle grow while the screen is being touched (Android)?

Tags: android, geometry, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm relatively new to Android and very new to graphics. I can draw a circle on the screen and even drag it around and grow (radius continues to increase) while it's moving, but when I just touch the screen, the circle does not increase in size. I presume this is because of the MotionEvent.

Essentially, what I want to do is have a circle increase in size whenever the screen is touched and move relative to the center of the circle when the user moves his finger, then reset to the original radius when the finger is lifted up. Any advice would be great or if someone knows of a tutorial that covers this that would be great too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onTouchEvent method, check the type of event using getActionMasked();

```
int eventType = event.getActionMasked();
if(eventType == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
   growCircle();
else if(eventType == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
  returnCircleToNormal();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... what you could do is override `onDraw()` and draw directly to the supplied canvas with `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint)`

Here is an explanation of the arguments:

- **bitmap** is the bitmap you want to use
- **src** is a `Rect` variable that allows you to pick what part if the bitmap you want to use... just use `null` if you want draw the whole bitmap
- **dst** is another `Rect` variable that is for where on the canvas you want to draw the bitmap. It will also scale your bitmap up if you set the points of the rectangle up from where they should be.
- Finally, just set **paint** to null

Answer (score 0):

In your `ACTION_DOWN` method start a thread which increases the radius of your circle every second. in `ACTION_UP` stop the thread and resize the circle to its original size.